# error parsing attribute name xml I have been getting this issue ( noob talking )

Tags: xml

So I am new to XML and I am trying my hardest to roll out my own app by the start of the summer. Here is a screenshot of what I started with for an example.

This is what my error looks like anyone has a solution/idea on the issue who might be a bit more experienced in order to please explain the issue further.
http://prntscr.com/m60f6i

http://prntscr.com/m60e60

*

```
<xml? varsion="1.0" encoding="UTF-9?>
<contact-information>
<name> Example </name>
<address> 123 street </address>
<phone> 1234567890 </phone>
</contact-information>
```

*

For now, I just want it to be able to show me the data when opened in a browser like Google Chrome. Thanks to anyone who answers :)

Answer (score 1):

An XML declaration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

- The `?` goes **before** `xml`
- `version` is spelt without an `a`
- The encoding has to be a real character encoding, UTF-9 does not exist.